# why natural join give output as empty set in following situation?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my `info` DB i have 4 tables, from which TWO are named as `girls` & `boys` and both have `id` column. `boys` contain 12 `id`(12 records) and`girls` contain 8 `id`. when i apply this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
boys
NATURAL JOIN
girls
```

i get output as

```
Empty Set
```

How could this happen? (both `id` column is `INT, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT`).

Comment: Because a boy cannot also be a girl. I mean that a person cannot be in both tables, if the tables were designed correctly.

Comment: can you explain in detail? i am new to DB.

Comment: You probably want something like a UNION rather than a join for getting all information stored in both tables. A natural join will result in showing only records that exist in both tables, which is not possible in the example you've given, as another user noted, if those tables were properly designed.

Comment: Are there records in Boys.id that match the value in girls.ID?  If not... that's why.

Comment: @RyanJ : but even if i run 'SELECT boys.first_name, girls.first_name FROM girls NATURAL JOIN boys;' again it give an empty set as output. and again both have same column name as id

Comment: @KiranChauhan alias will not work in this case. Check my answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NATURAL JOIN` is shorthand for an INNER JOIN with equality predicates on columns of the same name.

For example, given two tables "m" and "f", which have columns named "id" and "name" in common, a NATURAL JOIN like this

```
 SELECT ...
   FROM m
NATURAL
   JOIN f
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM m
  JOIN f
    ON f.id = m.id
   AND f.name = m.name
```

Only rows that "match" in the two tables will be returned in the result, all other rows are not returned.

For example, if we had table contents:

```
m: id  name
   --  ---------------
    1  peter
    2  paul
    4  michael jackson

f: id  name
   --  ---------------
    3  mary
    4  michael jackson
```

The queries above would return only the rows from "m" and "f" that have id=4 (as a single row), because those are the only rows that "match".

Comment: If you have an example that has the table definition, sample data, and the desired result, you could ask another question. (I only answered here the question you asked.)

Comment: Haha fantastic example

Answer (score 1):

Natural join will only work if the same named columns' values are same. ie if ID and Name both are same in both the tables.

If you need result like this :
[image: Result]
Then you must name the 'name' col different in both the tables.

If you want a set of all boys and girls, you should use UNION.

```
select * from boys
union
select * from girls
```

Example :

Boys Table
[image: Boys Table]

Girls Table
[image: Girls Table]

Natural Join
[image: Natural Join]

Union Result
[image: Union]

Answer (score 0):

[Natural Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) The `NATURAL [LEFT] JOIN` of two tables is defined to be semantically equivalent to an `INNER JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN` with a `USING` clause that names all columns that exist in both tables.

What this means is if you have any column name in common between the two tables, those are also being compared, and those rows are likely eliminated.